# After making a mistake while citing, BibTex doesn't run anymore

Tags: bibtex

Sometimes I make an error while trying to cite in LaTeX (I use TeXstudio and MiKTeX 2.9). After this, LaTeX generally doesn't want to create any output. I tend to solve this by deleting all files in the folder I'm working from that are not .tex or .bib (sometimes just deleting .bbl and .blg is enough).

This time, however, I typed `\[for an extensive overview]citet{matthewson2004}` instead of `\citet[for an estensive overview]{matthewson2004}`. After this, no output was generated.

I tried running latex then bibtex then latex then latex, after running bibtex I get the following message:

```
>Process started: bibtex.exe "Proposal"
>
>This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
>The top-level auxiliary file: Proposal.aux
>I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Proposal.aux
>I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Proposal.aux
>(There were 2 error messages)
>
>Process exited normally
```

This is a part of my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{tipa} 
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}

\begin{document}
\title{Preliminary thesis proposal}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section*{Introduction}
Blablabla \citep{aikhenvald2004evidentiality}. Blabla.

\bibliography{Aymarabib}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing all "generated" files (such as the `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.blg`, `.out`, `.log`) from your directory and then running `latex` followed by `bibtex`?

Comment: Yes, I get the same message as I posted: found no bibdata and bibstyle. When running latex, it says in the first log line 'file ended while scanning use of \emph'.

Comment: Did you also remove the aux-file and the toc?

Comment: Yes, absolutely everything save my .bib and .tex files.

Comment: If it says 'file ended while scanning use of \emph' you may want to double check your source files to make sure all braces `{` and `}` are paired properly.

Comment: I did not change anything in the source file (if you mean bibtex by that) between the last time I successfully ran latex and when I tried to do this after typing a mistake in my citation. I also tried removing the whole line with the citation in it, but as I knew from previous experience, this did not work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to an independent syntax error in the document.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a misplaced {, one that I had typed in the same 'session' as the citing mistake. So while LaTeX told me that it couldn't find my references, the problem was actually a brace. Thank you Willie Wong.